# sobreescritura al crear una lista de listas

Tags: python

Hola saben porqué al intentar correr el código adjunto de abajo la lista de listas va sobreescribiendo cada sublista de elemento creada en cada iteración del bucle for, en vez de ir acumulando cada una como elemento diferente.

```
import random

l1 = []

lst = []

for i in range(7):
    l1.clear()
    l1.append(random.randint(5, 15))
    l1.append(random.randint(5, 15))
    l1.append(random.randint(5, 15))
    print(l1)
    lst.append(l1)
   
print(lst)
```

cuando se imprime `print(l1)` se obtiene esto:

```
[12, 5, 8]
[11, 12, 14]
[15, 14, 7]
[10, 15, 7]
[6, 12, 6]
[7, 9, 5]
[9, 13, 5]
```

y al imprimir la lista de listas, en este caso lst,yo quiero obtener esto:
`[[12, 5, 8],[11, 12, 14],[15, 14, 7],[10, 15, 7],[6, 12, 6],[7, 9, 5],[9, 13, 5]]`
pero al final obtengo esto:

`[[9, 13, 5], [9, 13, 5], [9, 13, 5], [9, 13, 5], [9, 13, 5], [9, 13, 5], [9, 13, 5]]`

Si alguien sabé porqué y cómo resolverlo se lo agradezco

Comment: La solución al probar tu código sería utilizar `l1 = []` en lugar de `l1.clear()` o utilizar `lst.append(l1.copy())` en lugar de `lst.append(l1)`. En cuanto al motivo, supongo que es por algo de la memoria pero espero que alguien con más experiencia lo pueda explicar a detalle ya que yo tampoco entiendo por que si cambio `l1.clear()` por `l1 = []` funciona  correctamente (Por eso mismo no redacto una respuesta sino solo un comentario).

Answer (score 0):

La manera en que lo he podido solucionar es la siguiente:

```
import random

l1 = []

lst = []

for i in range(7):
    l1.clear()
    l1.append(random.randint(5,15))
    l1.append(random.randint(5,15))
    l1.append(random.randint(5,15))
    lst.append(l1[0:3])

    print(l1)  

print(lst)
```

De alguna manera que no puedo explicar por que, cada vez que se generaba una nueva lista en l1 la replicaba por el numero de elementos que tenía en ese momento lst.

Comment: Las listas son objetos mutables, es decir si tu modificas una lista en realidad si se modifica y no se crea una nueva en su lugar. En tu código como solo usas una lista estas agregando esa misma lista i veces. Por lo tanto cada elemento de `lst` es la misma lista y al modificar tan solo una de ellas modificas las demás (ya que es la misma) . Creo que podría hacer una respuesta para explicar mejor esto.

Comment: @Christian, si sería bueno, lo que yo no entiendo es, como puse en mi comentario, ¿Por qué al usar `l1=[]` en lugar de `l1.clear()` funciona correctamente? ¿Acaso es porque la primera opción crea la lista y la segunda solo modifica la que ya existe?

Comment: @HeytalePazguato exactamente es así. Al usar `l1=[]` se crea una nueva lista en cada iteración, en cambio con `l1.clear()` solo se modifica la actual. El valor que se guarda en esa dirección de memoria se borra pero la dirección de memoria sigue siendo la misma tanto para esa como para las demás listas agregadas anterior y posteriormente. Esto por ser un dato mutable.

Comment: Excelente respuesta @Christian , buscando en internet entontré algo que explica tambien acerca de la manera correcta e incorrecta de crear listas, solo que esta en inglés [enlace] (https://thispointer.com/how-to-create-and-initialize-a-list-of-lists-in-python/)

Comment: Me parece que había una respuesta que explicaba esto, pero no la encuentro. Seguiré buscando y si no encuentro nada entonces pondré una respuesta :D.